# Not able to install cloudstorage

Tags: python, cloud-storage

after installing cloudstorage module using pip when i am trying to import 
getting following error.

```
import cloudstorage
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/keshaw/vinv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudstorage/__init__.py", line 56
    def get_driver(driver: DriverName) -> Drivers:
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried instaling different versions also but same issues

Comment: show your code so that we can see where you may have gone wrong

Comment: It's not code I just typed. `import cloudstorage`

Answer (score 2):

Are you using python3? It seems that there is syntax error. `Typing` is not available in python2.
Python2:

```
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:48:08) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170118] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def get_driver(driver: str) -> str:
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    def get_driver(driver: str) -> str:
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Python3:

```
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 14 2017, 22:58:41) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170406] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def get_driver(driver: str) -> str:
...
```

In python3 your syntax should work :)

Comment: No, I am using python2.

Comment: you'll need to write a script and run it, not just one line at a time @Keshaw_pathak

Comment: @Keshaw_pathak please use python3. Your code will not work with python2. I have edited my answer.

Comment: I am not getting you I just typed in python terminal and It should work `import cloudstorage` and i used in script also got `import error` so to debug I typed in python console.

Comment: @Laszlowaty  It is  not my code I imported a package

Comment: @Keshaw_pathak try importing it with python3, instead of python2. It will work then. Just remember to install package for python3 :)

Comment: yeah got it its for python3 not for python2.