# Best practices with google cloud app engine: Python2 or Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am new to Google Cloud Platform and in my whole I have been working on Python 3. I am trying to find out which version of Python is more complete for Google App Engine: Python 2.7 or Python 3.

As I'm starting to work with Google App Engine I have realised that continuing using Python 3 seems too painful as basic tools like `dev_appserver.py` are written for [Python 2 only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46432589/how-to-use-python-3-with-google-app-engines-local-development-server). Now I am hitting the opposite problem: `cloudstorage` module [seems to exist only for python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47009532/not-able-to-install-cloudstorage). Again, when I install it, seems the only way I can test read/write to google bucket locally is by authenticating with `google.appengine.ext`, which in turn only works within `dev_appserver.py` or remotely. This leaves me confused which environment to chose.

What is a general agreement / what is the focus of Google App Engine: Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: ...point of clarification: by "Google Cloud Engine," do you mean "Google Compute Engine?"

Comment: Google App Engine Cloud -- correted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In App Engine, you have to options: the [Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/) environment and the [Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/) environment.

Python 2.7 is available in both [Standard and Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/runtime), while Python 3.6 is only available in [Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime).

Also, the choice between Standard and Flexible depends on what you want to do/what libraries you need:

- There are some [third-party libraries already built-in](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27) in the Standard Environment, and you can include [other libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27), but, those libraries **can't** include C extensions, they must be written in pure Python. If you need libraries with C extensions, you will have to move to [Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime#using_c_libraries_with_python).
- In Standard, you can use propietary libraries (like `google.appengine.ext`, as you mentioned) to do tasks like accessing databases, while in Flexible you can use other libraries (like the [client](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python) you mentioned).

There are also another [important differences](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments), like pricing, scaling, etc. The choice will depend, as I said, in your needs for your application.

**EDIT**

`dev_appserver.py` is only used when developing in Standard. There is a tutorial [in here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/python-standard-env), with Flask. If you are in Flexible, you can test the app locally as if you were running as usual a python file, like in [this other example](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/quickstart).

You can use buckets in both [Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage) and [Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-storage)

Comment: Well, as said I need to be able to test the app locally with something like `dev_appserver.py` and be able to use bucket storage. Both seem to be in the scope of standard, google-specific applications. One works only on 2 and the other on 3. Am I missing something?

Comment: The response is out of date. At the time of writing, appegnine standard does support python 3.

Answer (score 2):

The python3-only cloudstorage support assumption based on the SO post you referenced is not correct:

- the import appears to be done in a regular python shell or as a standalone script, not from a standard environment GAE app - different things, see [import cloudstorage, ImportError: No module named google.appengine.api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48564834/import-cloudstorage-importerror-no-module-named-google-appengine-api/48565916#48565916).
- it is not specified where that library comes from

GCS is definitely supported in the standard env GAE (i.e. on python 2), you just need to follow the steps from the official documentation: [Setting Up Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage) and [Reading and Writing to Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage).

Answer (score 0):

Both were good. But the question is what kind of environment do you want? Standard environment or Flexible environment.

Find your answer in this document: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends on what you're using it for. If you're doing data science, for example, I'm seeing a few notices of Python libraries that are (finally) dropping support for Python 2. `numpy` is one that is [dropping support](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/neps/dropping-python2.7-proposal.html).

Generally speaking, I would recommend Python 3 over Python 2. Why spend time developing in an aging version when its replacement has matured nicely and is more consistent?

Comment: I know, but this is a general advise not pertaining to Google App Engine.

Comment: I realize that, and if you’re using this App Engine for data science, package support is something to keep in mind when selecting your language version. Another thing to keep in mind is that GCP is constantly evolving and growing - they are way better than they were a year ago - and it is reasonable to expect that at some point, Python 3 will be their standard moving forward.